# Passing variable from javascript to php get statement

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

I looked for this in previous threads so apologies if has been answered. My javascript is the following, where the data parameter is a string which refers to a table in a MySQL database:

```
    getData("UKnatgas");

function getData(data){
$.getJSON("service.php?action="+data, function(json) {              
    $.each(json.UKnatgas,function() {
       var info = this.UKnatgas;                    
                $('#UKnatgas').append( info );
    });
});
}
```

Firstly, I want to pass the string "UKnatgas" into the sub $.each function so that it would read:

```
$.each(json.data,function() {
       var info = this.data;                    
                $('#data').append( info );
    });
```

But this doesn't work? Could you tell me why?

The second part is getting rid of all instances of "UKnatgas" in the php file:

```
  if($_GET){
if($_GET['action'] == 'UKnatgas'){
    $query = "SELECT UKnatgas FROM UKnatgas order by Date DESC Limit 1 ";
    $result = db_connection($query);

    $UKnatgas = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($UKnatgas, array('UKnatgas' => $row['UKnatgas']));
    }
    echo json_encode(array("UKnatgas" => $UKnatgas));
    exit;
    }
}
```

So to summarise, I'd like to initialise the function getData(data) with a string which is propagated into the javascript function and then the php file. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use the `data` argument in the function call? It's a lot easier than the way you do it now

Comment: Thanks Wouter. I'm not sure I follow you. I thought I was doing that i.e. getData(data) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP is easy, although I would allow for some type of check for errors and maybe even check for hack attempts as you are putting a user editable string. This may allow for `MySQL Injection` so be careful.

If you can, use `mysql_real_escape_string` when ever possible. See link for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
if($_GET['action']){
    $query = "SELECT `".$_GET['action']."` FROM `".$_GET['action']."` order by Date DESC Limit 1 ";
    $result = db_connection($query);

    $actionArray = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($actionArray, array($_GET['action'] => $row[$_GET['action']]));
    }
    echo json_encode(array($_GET['action'] => $actionArray));
    exit;
}
```

And not sure exactly but this should work for the JSON

```
$.each(json, function(key, val) {
    $('#'+data).append( val );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

I tested it in your case and you will need to do the following to access the data. Now this is using JSON as an Associative Array which it isn't, but not 100% how to do it otherwise.

```
function getData(data) { 
    $.getJSON("service.php?action="+data, function(json) { 
        $.each(json[data], function() { 
            var info = this[data];
            $('#'+data).append( info ); 
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I tried the php code, however nothing happened. No erro rs but it didn't append the natgas as the code I have in the example above does. The JSON code throws up the error: "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild] http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js Line 18"

Comment: With the PHP script it looks correct to me. did you try `service.php?action=UKnatgas` and see what it outputted?

Comment: Yep, actually there's no errors in that case, but the natgas price still doesn't appear. The example I'm trying to get working is here http://whichchart.com/ if that helps.

Comment: Take out the `mysql_real_escape_string` because I don't think your php has that. Use example above.

Comment: I updated the link back to the way it was in the example to show where it should appear.

Comment: Ah, yes that works! Thanks. Now if that JSON thing was working that would be great but I'll give you the tick in a while. Thanks.

Comment: It's in a Javascript object. When I get home I will post how

Comment: Great success! You the man - saved me a lot of redundant code! I'll look into SQL injection proofing it when I have something worth protecting!